# How do I get Adobe Reader to print more than one page in 13.10 Saucy?

Tags: printing, pdf, adobe-reader

On my fresh saucy install (64-bit), acroread (9.5.5) only prints one page out of any PDF file. Setting `File > Print > Advanced > Font and Resource Policy` to `Send for each page` did not help.

`/var/log/cups/error_log` contains no errors.

Evince prints the same pdf files fine. When I print to a ps file in acroread, the file opens fine in Evince and contains all of the pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1247935, for me the fix was to purge cups and start again defining printers from scratch; I'd copied the config files from a previous Ubuntu and something had obviously not liked it.

Answer (score 0):

To correct this issue, go ahead and start to print the document, but before you actually send the print job to the printer, select Advanced and — under the Font and Resource Policy — select Send for Each Page. This will ensure the printer is getting all the data it needs to print the complete document.

After you change this setting once, you should not have to do so again.

Comment: As I said in my orginal post, this is already set.